# Git fork и clone репозитория

Tags: git, github

Будет ли видно, что я форкаю чужой репозиторий. А если склонирую, автор увидит (или это где-то отобразится не только у автора, а общедоступно)?

И еще, чем, собственно, отличается форк от клона. Уже много статей прочёл, но так до конца понимания не пришло.

Answer (score 2):

**Clone** - это "скачивание" репозитория на локальную машину (этот репозиторий будет включать всю информацию, которая хранилась в удаленном репозитории на github). Сделать клон можно любого публичного репозитория и вы может работать с ним локально как захотите, но вот если вы захотите поделиться своими наработками, то запушить в оригинальный репозиторий их будет нельзя (у вас просто не будет доступа).

Автор может отслеживать количество клонов, но кто их конкретно делал не думаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Fork** - это фича github, которая позволяет создать полноценную копию репозитория в вашем аккаунте. У вас появятся полный доступ с этому репозиторию, как хотите так и развлекайтесь. Я чаще это использую, когда хочу поделиться с автором репозитория своими наработками/фиксами. Создаешь форк, делаешь изменения, комитиш/пушишь в свой репозиторий, а уже github позволяет создать pull request и позже автор оригинального репозиторяю может их принять (т.е. если вам это все не нужно, а просто нужно запустить/собрать проект, то обычного клона хватит, также если вы раньше делали клон, это не мешает сделать форк, и потом его использовать).

Форк публичны, свободно можно посмотреть кто делал форк (во вкладке `Insights` -> `Forks`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данной картинке, оригинальный репозиторий `dotnet/roslyn`, а ниже все кто сделал форк.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развёрнутый ответ. А можно у вас еще уточнить. Если мне нужно только копия чужого репозитория на свой аккаунт, чтобы в дальнейшем там кодить, но изменения я не хочу предлагать автору оригинального репозитория. То есть просто скопировать его проект себе и там делать, что захочу. Вот тогда команды clone и fork будут являться одинаковыми? У меня же проект будет храниться по одному адресу. Все изменения скопируются и тд? Только разница в том, что с форкнутым РЕПО я могу делать пулл реквест в оригинальный РЕПО? А с склонированным не могу?

Comment: @Pavel clone/fork будут равны, если вы вообще не собираетесь взаимодействовать с github, тогда и можно делать обычный clone, в вашем случае, если вы сделаете клон, то залить свои изменения на github не сможете, т.к. у вас на аккаунте не будет репозитория

Comment: @Pavel clone - это комманда для `git`, которая будет работать везде где есть доступ для чтения (не обязательно github), а fork - это возможность github, которая создает копия репозитория, для работы с гитхабом

Comment: Наконец-то разобрался полностью. Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 1):

clone - это Вы копируете репозиторий себе. Да, где то в логах это останется. Но скорее всего никто об этом не узнает так просто.

fork - это я бы сказал такая себе полуприватная ветка (или даже ветки), просто она размещается в аккаунте другого человека (Вашем аккаунте). Поэтому автор естественно может видеть факт этого. И это как раз облегчает дальнейшую интеграцию. И никакой магии.